# How to solve error in importing matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, computation

Whenever I try to import matplotlib 3.8.3 in Python 3.12, it gives this error:

```
 import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\SSHOP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 272, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\SSHOP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 266, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SSHOP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SSHOP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: pip install msvc-runtime